# JQuery removeClass not working when paired with addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button and some text. When I click the button I want the text to be hidden and a different line of text to be shown:

```
<button type="button" id=button>Click Me!</button>

<div id="a">
This is a line of text

<div id ="b" class="hidden">
This is also a line of text
```

Jquery:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
     $('#b').removeClass('hidden');
     $('#a').addClass('hidden');    
});
```

However it only hides the original line of text and doesn't show the second line. However when I do this:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
     $('#b').removeClass('hidden');
     // $('#a').addClass('hidden');
    });
```

Both lines of text are displayed.  Its only when I add the 2 lines together the problem arises.

Comment: b is child of a... so it will get hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not closed `div` properly.

```js
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
     $('#b').removeClass('hidden');
     $('#a').addClass('hidden');    
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id=button>Click Me!</button>   
<div id="a">
This is a line of text
</div>

<div id ="b" class="hidden">
This is also a line of text
</div>
```

Comment: well that's embarrassing. In my defence I normally use HAML :(. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use jQuery hide and show methods

```js
$('#b').hide();
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
     $('#b').show();
     $('#a').hide();    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id=button>Click Me!</button>   
<div id="a">
This is a line of text
</div>

<div id ="b" >
This is also a line of text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to close the div tag.

```js
$("#button" ).click(function() {
     $('#b').removeClass('hidden');
     $('#a').addClass('hidden');    
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id=button>Click Me!</button>
<div id="a">
  This is a line of text
</div>
<div id="b" class="hidden">
  This is also a line of text 
</div>
```